# Changing the fragmentmanager not recognize the buttons and fails

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

Very good.
I recently met a problem I had when declaring buttons on other fragments that were to contain another fragment.
Thanks to this forum and @Shudy could solve the problem.
This is the last post: 
[When declaring buttons different fragments does not recognize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231635/when-declaring-buttons-different-fragments-does-not-recognize)

But now for the needs I had to change the way I had embedded a fragment of the buttons and when I run the app. I get an error that is not how to fix.

This is the code I modified

```
public class Grp1Fragment extends Fragment {

private int ContArrayAsk = 0;
private int ContRight = 0;
private int ContFailed= 0;

private Button buttonTrue;
private Button buttonFalse;
private Button buttonNextAsk;
private Button buttonShareScore;

private View view;

String[] arrayFragmentAResultsGrp1 = new String[]{"0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1",};

private Fragment[] fragmentsChangeAsk = new Fragment[]{
                                                new Grp1FragmentP1(),
                                                new Grp1FragmentP2(),
                                                new Grp1FragmentP3(),
};

private Fragment[] fragmentsChangeButton = new Fragment[]{
                                                new TrueoFalseFragment(),
                                                new NextAskFragment(),
                                                new ShareScoreFragment(),
};


public Grp1Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor


}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grp1, container, false);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager managerAsk = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    managerAsk.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentaskGRP1, fragmentsChangeAsk[0])
            .add(R.id.fragmentaskGRP1, fragmentsChangeAsk[1])
            .add(R.id.fragmentaskGRP1, fragmentsChangeAsk[2])
            .hide(fragmentsChangeAsk[1])
            .hide(fragmentsChangeAsk[2])
            .commit();

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager managerButton = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    managerButton.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentButton, fragmentsChangeButton[0])
            .add(R.id.fragmentButton, fragmentsChangeButton[1])
            .add(R.id.fragmentButton, fragmentsChangeButton[2])
            .hide(fragmentsChangeButton[1])
            .hide(fragmentsChangeButton[2])
            .commit();


    buttonTrue = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttontrue);
    buttonTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You pressed the button: True", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //ContArrayAsk++;
                //setContent(ContArrayAsk);

        }
    });

    buttonFalse = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonfalse);
    /*buttonFalse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ha pulsado el botón falso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });*/

    buttonNextAsk = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonnextask);
    buttonShareScore = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonsharescore);


    /*buttonNextAsk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ha pulsado el botón siguiente pregunta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });*/

    return view;
}

public void setContent(int index){

    Fragment toHide1 = null;
    Fragment toHide2 = null;
    Fragment toHide3 = null;
    Fragment toHide4 = null;
    Fragment toHide5 = null;
    Fragment toHide6 = null;
    Fragment toHide7 = null;
    Fragment toHide8 = null;
    Fragment toHide9 = null;
    Fragment toShow = null;

    switch (index){
        case 0:
            toHide1 = fragmentsChangeAsk[1];
            toHide2 = fragmentsChangeAsk[2];
            toShow = fragmentsChangeAsk[0];
            break;
        case 1:
            toHide1 = fragmentsChangeAsk[0];
            toHide2 = fragmentsChangeAsk[2];
            toShow = fragmentsChangeAsk[1];
            break;
        case 2:
            toHide1 = fragmentsChangeAsk[1];
            toHide2 = fragmentsChangeAsk[0];
            toShow = fragmentsChangeAsk[2];
            break;

    }
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager managerAsk = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    managerAsk.beginTransaction()
            .hide(toHide1)
            .hide(toHide2)
            .show(toShow)
            .commit();

}


}
```

The error is when I uncommented the following line of code:

```
buttonTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You pressed the button: True", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //ContArrayAsk++;
                //setContent(ContArrayAsk);

        }
    });
```

The layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Grp1"
    android:id="@+id/textGrp1"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>



<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentaskGRP1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textGrp1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout where I have the buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_TrueorFalse">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="120sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="@string/buttontrue"
        android:id="@+id/buttontrue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="@string/buttonfalse"
        android:id="@+id/buttonfalse"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And this is the error that gives me the logcat:**

```
04-01 11:43:58.279      492-492/josejuansosarodriguez.radioecca.conocecanarias E/AndroidRuntime﹕ Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-01 11:43:58.289      492-492/josejuansosarodriguez.radioecca.conocecanarias E/AndroidRuntime﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{josejuansosarodriguez.radioecca.conocecanarias/josejuansosarodriguez.radioecca.conocecanarias.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at FragmentsDrawer.Grp1Fragment.onCreateView(Grp1Fragment.java:87)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3723)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
        at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     04-01 11:43:58.299      492-495/josejuansosarodriguez.radioecca.conocecanarias I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
     04-01 11:43:58.309      492-495/josejuansosarodriguez.radioecca.conocecanarias     E/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

I hope I have spread far. Thank you very much for everything, this forum is amazing.

Comment: line 87 is causing a null pointer which line is this?

Comment: Line 87 is: public void onClick(View v) {
I do not understand why, if it worked before

Comment: does this error show when you click a button or as soon as the application runs?

Comment: as soon as the application runs

Comment: the problem is the way your accessing your views. You cant add an onclick listener to a null button reference. see answer below

Answer (score 0):

With Fragments:

Inflate and return only your view in onCreateView()

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grp1, container, false);

   return view;
}
```

then reference your View Elements in onViewCreated() and add your listeners:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


buttonTrue = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttontrue);

buttonTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You pressed the button: True", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //ContArrayAsk++;
            //setContent(ContArrayAsk);

    }
});

buttonFalse = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonfalse);
/*buttonFalse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ha pulsado el botón falso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});*/

buttonNextAsk = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonnextask);
buttonShareScore = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonsharescore);


/*buttonNextAsk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ha pulsado el botón siguiente pregunta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});*/



}
```

Then perform the heavier operations once the onActivityCreated callback is received.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

         android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager managerAsk = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
managerAsk.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragmentaskGRP1, fragmentsChangeAsk[0])
        .add(R.id.fragmentaskGRP1, fragmentsChangeAsk[1])
        .add(R.id.fragmentaskGRP1, fragmentsChangeAsk[2])
        .hide(fragmentsChangeAsk[1])
        .hide(fragmentsChangeAsk[2])
        .commit();

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager managerButton = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
managerButton.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragmentButton, fragmentsChangeButton[0])
        .add(R.id.fragmentButton, fragmentsChangeButton[1])
        .add(R.id.fragmentButton, fragmentsChangeButton[2])
        .hide(fragmentsChangeButton[1])
        .hide(fragmentsChangeButton[2])
        .commit();

}
```

Additionally you should be checking to make sure your View elements are not null before doing any operations with them...

ex..

```
  if(buttonTrue != null){
        buttonTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You pressed the button: True", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //ContArrayAsk++;
            //setContent(ContArrayAsk);

    }
});
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ inner_class7. I used the code you have given me, and I get no error when running it. But when I click on the botontrueno do anything.
Below I put the code as it looks.